# Does re-installing with apt-get (ubuntu-desktop) delete my data or files?

Tags: display, settings

I'm new to Ubuntu, I am unable to click on "Display" settings , I found that the command below can fix it

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

My question is if this command safe to use? Or do I have to create a backup of my files first?

Comment: That will re-install the `ubuntu-desktop` package, which will not impact your files.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried the command and I am now able to open my desktop settings. cheers.  My files are safe too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: the command is safe, yes. The command is not in itself a cause for a backup. And no it does not touch your personal files.

All `apt-get` does is to re-install that package with it's dependencies. Without checking, I suspect that is just a meta-package to ensure that all the useful tools you need should be installed.

In general, as long as you don't add any PPAs or similar, doing an `apt-get` command should never affect your personal files. If you do things like purge, it can affect global configurations (e.g. apache configurations), but for most every-day users that is not a problem, and if you're unsure you can just use remove instead of purge.

Comment: Sorry answering this with "yes" is incorrect. The answer is always "no". No command is safe and you must always ensure beforehand you understand the actions of a command and the course to take when a command fails -for whatever reason-. That command will run for minutes and just a mere power cut during it is fatal for that system and will require more than average knowledge to fix the issue.

Comment: @Rinzwind care to elaborate? Does this command run any scripts that does unsafe modifications, or anything like that?

Comment: "The command is not in itself a cause for a backup"  this alone is worth downvoting.

Comment: @Rinzwind as already stated OP is asking about this specific command, not external factors. If you include external factors like that the answer become moot. If the command does not modify any personal settings and leaves the system in a consistent state it is safe within the boundaries of the command (which is what the question is about). If we do not stick to those boundaries, then answering questions like this is pointless. So if this command does not run unsafe modifications, then the answer is yes within the scope set by the question

Comment: @Rinzwind why is it worth down voting for that? Does this specific command do any modifications in personal data that is a direct cause for a backup? If that is the case, what modifications does it do?